# Java EE installed in eclipse but dynamic project, jsp, and other options gone missing

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee

I have installed eclipse for java ee. I've been making some projects for java ee. Options were present and 100% java ee is installed since I can make new servlets and JSPs.

When i tried to create a java project (not dynamic web project), a dialog box appeared and i suddenly clicked on OK button without reading. 
After that, dynamic web project , Jsp file, and servlets, etc. gone missing.

Evidence they are installed: 
[image]

But options are gone
[image]

I want the old options back I don't know how to do it.

My eclipse is eclipse jee 2018-12

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like you accidentally switched to the ***Java* perspective** (the shortcuts offered in the *File > New* submenu vary depending on the perspective).

Switch back to the ***Java EE* perspective**:

***Window > Perspective: Open Perspective > Other...: Java EE (default)***

Comment: that's what I've been doing. I'm finding the Java EE perspective but didn't see the "other" options. I saw the java ee option now.